# How do I pass data to new widget without getting a Null value as the first then the data I passed to the widget

Tags: flutter, routes

I tried sending data from a widget to another widget. Each time I tried to retrieve this data a Null data is first then the data I sent. Something like this(I sent this data as a Map):
The first data that I did not send{data: null}
The data I sent{data: I am a Girl}

Widget sending the data

```
class _LoadingState extends State<Loading> {
  void setUpWorldTime() async {
    WorldTime example = WorldTime(
        location: 'Berlin', url: "Europe/Berlin", flag: 'germany.png');
    await example.getTime();

    //reroute to the home page and pass these data called arguments
    //just like rendering django pages in py
    Navigator.pushReplacementNamed(context, '/home', arguments: {
      'url': example.url,
      'flag': example.flag,
      'location': example.location
    });
```

Receiveing widget

```
 Map data = {};

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    data = {'data': ModalRoute.of(context)?.settings.arguments};
    print(data);
```

Returned data from the console
{data: Null}
{data: {location: 'Berlin', url: "Europe/Berlin", flag: 'germany.png'}}

I can access the data since the data and the Null have the same key and the Null is the  first

What I expected
{data:{location: 'Berlin', url: "Europe/Berlin", flag: 'germany.png'}}

I`ve done this as well
data  = ModalRoute.of(context)?.settings.arguments as Map
the error is one value is retruning a Null

Answer (score 0):

You can check for the null value and ignore it before saving it in `data` object.

```
@override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    var route? = ModalRoute.of(context);
    if (route != null) {
        data = {'data': route!.settings.arguments};
        if (data != null) print(data);
    }
```

Comment: It`s still now working, still giving me the null data first then the data I sent

Comment: Pl try the revised code.

Comment: I`ve tried it worked at first or each time I restart my text editor but stops after hot reload or start. I don`t know if its with sdk of something else. I created a new application, copy and pasted the documentation into the new app, the same thing happened works a first then stop

Comment: If the code of the spp is short, pl revise your question by providing the full code.